# Wireless adapter disabled by fn. Key

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I turned off my wifi on my ProBook 4540s by one of the FN keys but I don't know which one.
I don't know how to turn it back on again.  Can you please help me?

I have tried turning the laptop off and on again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a wifi logo on or above the key. Hold down FN and press that key. That should turn it on. You might also be able to go into your network control panel and turn it on from there. Also check your system tray for a networking icon, there may be a vendor-specific control for that function.